# How to assign all values in dictionary to variables based on max value

Tags: python, dictionary

List contains dictionaries and their values are again list. How to print max value and country name from the values.

```
data = [{'country':[2,'US']},{'country':[1,'EN']}]
```

Example: In values 2 is maximum and the country is 'US' so it should print instead of another dictionary. I ran the code below but I didn't get the desired result on, how to be more efficient.

```
for i in data:
    for m,j in i.items():
        country = j[1][1]
        points = j[1][0]


Example Output:

points = 2
country = 'US'
```

Comment: @Mark no both are country

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try:

```
data = [{'country': [2, 'US']}, {'country': [1, 'EN']}]

max_dic = max(data, key=lambda x: x['country'][0])
points, country = max_dic['country']

print(country)
print(points)
```

Answer (score 1):

The below seems to work

```
_max = (-1,None) # assuming max cant be negative
data = [{'country':[2,'US']},{'country':[1,'EN']}]
for entry in data:
    if entry['country'][0] > _max[0]:
        _max = tuple(entry['country'])
print(_max)
```

output

```
(2, 'US')
```